# Xpath expression to browse to next page

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to write an XPATH expression that finds the next page URL **OR** element on this page to navigate to the next page.

It looks something like as follows, where 1, 2, 3, ..., n, and 'More' navigates to pages

Page 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | More

Page source as follows:

```
<table><tr><td><br />   

        <p>Page <a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=0'>1</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=20'>2</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=40'>3</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=60'><strong>4</strong></a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=80'>5</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=100'>6</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=120'>7</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=140'>8</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=160'>9</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=180'>10</a> |&nbsp;<a href='browse.html?&id=0&count=200'>More</a> </p>

</td></tr></table>
```

I've tried writing a few but to no avail:

//table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/p

//td/p

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, pagination or even visiting any level of a site, totally depends on each site. So there isn't a general way to paginate any site, with any tool.

Now, talking about this specific case, it looks like the site pagination only depends on the `count` url variable, so you can emulate pagination very easily with just a counter, no need to use xpath or get any part of the html:

- `browse.html?&id=0&count=0` , `count=(0*1) + 20`
- `browse.html?&id=0&count=20` , `count=(1*1) + 20`
- `browse.html?&id=0&count=40` , `count=(2*1) + 20`
- ...

If you need xpath this should return all your links:

```
//a/@href
```

And if you want an index to iterate with xpath, it could also be done with:

- `//a[1]/@href`
- `//a[2]/@href`
- ...

Comment: I noted that it is simple pseudo-code to enumerate through the pages, however I specifically require it to be in xpath but wasn't sure how to translate. What I have now is: //p/a/following-sibling::a[1], which retrieves the correct element, however how do I use xpath to enumerate? i.e. n+1, where n is looped? i.e. //p/a/following-sibling::a[(n*1)+20]

Comment: that makes sense. however, is there a way to iterate in xpath with one single line of code? Tried searching but to no avail, only result was using position(), i.e. //a[position()>=1 and position()<=20]/@href, however this does not pull any information

Comment: I would say there is no way to iterate on xpath (other than using the index I shared with you). Can't you use some other programming language to iterate with different xpath every time?

Comment: Not an issue - just thought there was a straight forward way to loop. Thank you